# Mysql script to create a column

Tags: php, mysql

I need a script which checks if the columns exists in the database, and if not create the missing column(s).
will the code under fits exactly to my requirement?

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = ‘management’ AND COLUMN_NAME = ‘lastname’)
BEGIN
  ALTER TABLE TEST ADD lastname VARCHAR
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that INFORMATION_SCHEMA isn't supported in MySQL prior to 5.0. Nor are stored procedures supported prior to 5.0, so if you need to support MySQL 4.1, this solution isn't good.

```
    IF NOT EXISTS( SELECT NULL
                FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
               WHERE table_name = 'management'
                 AND table_schema = 'db_name'
                 AND column_name = 'lastname')  THEN

      ALTER TABLE `management ` ADD `lastname ` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL;

END IF;
```

Another solution would be to just try the

```
ALTER TABLE ADD lastname VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL;
```

. It should throw an error if the column already exists.

ERROR 1060 (42S21): Duplicate column name 'lastname'
Catch the error and disregard it in your upgrade script.